# Libreoffice: sum of column except one cell

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to calculate the sum of the A column excluding A1, because I want the result there. Illustration:

```
        A                    B      C
1    =SUM(A2:Ainfinite)
2     1234
3     5678
...
```

I could write `A2:A1048576` which would work to some degree, but it would not be elegant or foolproof. Is there any notation to express the range from A 2 to A infinite?

Comment: You should really check to see if the [question has been asked before](http://superuser.com/q/276638/76571) before posting a bounty.

Comment: @Excellll You should really read. That is about Excel, this is about LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ehm, I am risking to say something silly here, but why don't you just

Get total number of rows:

```
ROWS(A:A)
```

Convert to coordinate of the last cell using INDIRECT:

```
(INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS(A:A))))
```

And use it in your SUM formula

```
 SUM(A2:(INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS(A:A)))))
```

I cannot guarantee that this is going to work, as I am currently logged into my Windows machine. But it works on MS Excel.

**UPDATE:** as correctly noted by tohuwawohu you will need to set formula syntax to `Excel A1`

Comment: This works with LibreOffice, too - provided that the formula syntax is set to `Excel A1`. In contrast to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/276653/84724), the solution calculates the last possible index without "hardcoding" it into the formula. Nice!

Comment: Is there a way to stop this breaking whenever I add a new row?

Answer (score 4):

With a current version of Libreoffice Calc (tested with 4.2), you can address the complete Column A with `A:A` (if `Formula syntax`in Tools -> Options -> Calc -> Formula is set to `Excel A1`).

But AFAIK there's no way to reference a difference (complement), something like *"`A:A` without `A1`"*. It would be great if `=SUM(OFFSET(A:A;1;0))` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that formula setting in Calc.  This also works with version 3.5.4.  Thanks.