# How to include an entire column starting at a particular row in a formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to do summary statistics on a column of varying lengths.

I want to do something like `=sum(A:A)` except I want to avoid the first 5 rows of column A. Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: Someone pointed out a possible duplicate. Except neither of the solutions in that question actually works. If someone is proposing to apply `ISBLANK()` to the whole column until the maximum index, I would like to see clarification on the different between that and formats such as `A:A` -- in terms of speed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum contents in column from starting cell on down without setting an explicit last cell index](http://superuser.com/questions/276638/sum-contents-in-column-from-starting-cell-on-down-without-setting-an-explicit-la)

Comment: What about this one instead? http://superuser.com/q/768775/76571

Comment: Sure. It's pretty inconvenient though

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use either `OFFSET`,  either `INDIRECT` to refer the custom range:

- `OFFSET(A5,0,0,ROWS(A:A)-ROW(A5)+1)`
- `INDIRECT("A5:A"&ROWS(A:A))`

Both result in a range from A5 to the bottom of the column.

Comment: Could you please provide a similar example of use `INDIRECT` function that returns the entire row starting at some particular column - e.g. the row 7 starting at the column C ? Thanks

Comment: I'd use offset for that. It's much more complicated with indirect.

Comment: Really? It seems like a concise range notation should be available for such a common case. Many spreadsheets have rows with headers. There are many other conventions in excel that acknowledge this. Why not "A5:A". This seems a logical extension of "A:A", meaning "all non-tempty cells in column A". How 'bout "A5:"? How bout a symbol that means "the theoretical end to non-empty data in A", like "$" (borrowed from regular extension line range notation)? Now "A5:A$" has the right semantics and is easily typed and remembered. OK. Microsoft flame-off.

Answer (score 4):

My workaround has been to use `(A5:A$1048576)`. Since the maximum number of rows in Excel is 1048576, this has the desired effect. The `$` is so placed to ensure the array doesn't break if I copy the formula to the next cell down.

Comment: On one hand, you have to type that number. On the other, this is massively inefficient. `A:A` already doesnt have auto detection of non-blank cells in a sparse sheet and instead naively check several thousand rows unless existing max row is higher, in which case I believe it proceeds to check the next several thousand. Forcing a check blank on 1 mil cell for every single instance should result in your sheet practically crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way:

```
=SUM(A:A)-SUM(A1:A5)
```

Comment: Does not work for non-numeric values.

Answer (score -1):

How about `=Sum($A6:A...`
The dollar sign makes it an absolute reference to the cell so if you copied it to B the columns 1-5 wouldn't be touched. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Why is dollar sign needed again? Would that make it `sum($A6:B...` when applying to column B?

Comment: I fixed typo. I meant 1-5 Rows 1 thru 5. So the Dollar Sign says only apply the function to row six.

Comment: How does $A6 apply to 6 rather than A?  Regardless, have you actually tested this?  At least in my version of Excel, this range specification produces an error.

Comment: Yeah $A a applies to A.                                                                                                       $A$6 applies to A6. Sorry for the confusion. I'll test and let you know if solved.